# Memcached Storage Per Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memcached

How could I determine how much memory each object is used in memcached? "stats item" command seems closest, but doesn't include usage. I'm thinking about doing it in Ruby - retrieve sample objects and use some memory measurement to measure their size. But not sure how accurate that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an object is key length + data length + data structure + a stringified "flags" field + 2 bytes. Plus or minus two bytes since I'm recalling this from memory :P

Note when I say "data length", for you that would be the serialized (marshalled/json'ed/etc) value before rails puts it in memcached. If you know the key, you could fetch it once by hand to get the length back.

You can find the data structure size by running the "./sizes" command out of a memcached tarball after running "make".

The total bytes in the system is "curr_bytes" as resulted from the "stats" command, but that doesn't account for flushed or expired items still in the cache.